# MySQL and correctly setting up partitions

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

Our customers are all part of the same database, where we store all of their images, blog posts, etc. I want to partition the tables to optimize performance for each and every one of their sites (specified by "site_id" in every table).

As an example, let's use our `images` table. Available columns are: image_id (int, primary, auto_inc), site_id (int, primary), width (int), height (int), filesize (int), uploaded (datetime).

I've tried just adding partitioning; `ALTER TABLE images PARTITION BY KEY(image_id,site_id)`, which worked. However, I have no way of knowing what MySQL uses to "group" the partitions - is it optimized for what I want? That's where you guys come in.

## Question 1

Is PARTITION BY KEY the correct way to set up a partition to get the site_id "separated" from each other? If not - how would you do it?

## Question 2

I've seen that people are manually adding the partitions - p0, p1, p2, p3, etc. Do you need to specify the number of partitions, or does MySQL "understand" that I'm after the site_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1**

If you use partition by key(image_id,site_id), you cannot be sure that each partition will only contain separated site_id's because this kind of partitionning will use a integrated hashing function on (image_id,site_id) and the result of this will determinate in wich partition the row will be inserted into.

If you want to ensure separation you should use [RANGE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-range.html) or [LIST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-list.html) partitionning.

**Question 2**

If using RANGE or LIST partitionning, you will have to define the number of partitions you want.
ie :

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (site_id) (
PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (6),
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (11),
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (16),
PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
);
```

LIST and RANGE requires a bit of maintenance. If new site_id are added / removed, you will have to adapt your partition scheme.

KEY partitioning will ensure a balanced row repartition across the number of partitions specified:

```
PARTITION BY KEY(image_id,site_id)
PARTITIONS 10;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, very informative. We have about 300 site_ids at the moment. Is it possible to add a partition by range to current range partitions, or do we have to drop the partition and create it from scratch every time a new site_id is created? I'm thinking we should have one partition per site_id. Or perhaps that's overkill?

Comment: Yes I think it's a bit overkill to partition by range with about 300 site_ids with one site_id by partition. You could make 10 partitions with 30 site_ids as an example

Comment: what I'm worried about is, if they're not separated - two site_ids using large amounts of data will be in the same partition, and screw each other up. With separate partitions they'd "all be safe". Anyway, is there a partition limit in a MySQL table?

Comment: What do you mean by "screw each other up" ?  From the doc : Maximum number of partitions.  Prior to MySQL 5.6.7, the maximum possible number of partitions for a given table not using the NDB storage engine was 1024. Beginning with MySQL 5.6.7, this limit is increased to 8192 partitions. Regardless of the MySQL Server version, this maximum includes subpartitions.

Comment: By "screw each other up" I only meant performance problems due to one partition getting most of the content. :) Thanks for your help. One last question - does PARTITION BY KEY has to be applied to both image_id and site_id columns, or is site_id sufficient?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. You can partition only on image_id if you want.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. Found a way to partition by last digit of the site_id in all tables. Works great. :)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL partitions is an OK way to go, but it sounds like you have an ideal case for sharding your database as well. There are easy ways to do it yourself for a simple use case like this, and more automated products that can do it too. This way you are not limited to a single server, you can expand the cluster as you get more usage, and you can even specifically allocate site_id keys to specific servers (giving preference to larger customers). For example, a really big customer can have their own shard server, then lots of smaller customers can be co-located on one or more other servers. If you have shared tables, there are ways to replicate GLOBAL tables across all shards. Parallel queries can be supported if you need to access data across all customers.

Comment: Sharding is, of course, interesting. For a simple solution, what would the setup look like?

Comment: You will need to partition the data across multiple servers, and have a method from your application to know what shard to go to for a given value. You can "roll your own" or there are tools to help. Here is a white paper we have that explains the technical approach, hope it's helpful. http://dbshards.com/dbshards/database-sharding-white-paper/